# number similar/duplicated rows in R

Tags: r

Hi I'm using R and I have a data like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 1 2 2
3 4 1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5
3 4 1 2 3
```

I want to number the identical lines together with the same number, for the above ex

```
1 2 3 4 5 --> 1
1 2 1 2 2 --> 2
3 4 1 2 3 --> 3
1 2 3 4 5 --> 1
3 4 1 2 3 --> 3
```

Does any know how to do this in R (for both numeric case and character case)?

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(do.call(paste, df)))`

Comment: If your data is in a data.frame then I'd look at something like df %>% group_by(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) using dplyr

Comment: Based on the linked post: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, num := .GRP, by = names(df)][]`

Comment: thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,3,1,3), 
                 b=c(2,2,4,2,4), 
                 c=c(3,1,1,3,1), 
                 d=c(4,2,2,4,2), 
                 e=c(5,2,3,5,3))
```

---

**Approach 1:**
You would need the `data.table` package to perform the below approach:

```
library(data.table)
i <- interaction(data.table(df), drop=TRUE)
df.out <- cbind(df, id=factor(i,labels=length(unique(i)):1))
```

This would give you the following:

```
#  a b c d e  id
#1 1 2 3 4 5   1
#2 1 2 1 2 2   3
#3 3 4 1 2 3   2
#4 1 2 3 4 5   1
#5 3 4 1 2 3   2
```

---

**Approach 2:**
Another approach is by using the `plyr` package, as follows:

```
library(plyr)
.id <- 0
df.out <- ddply(df, colnames(df), transform, id=(.id<<-.id+1))
```

This will give you the following output:

```
#  a b c d e  id
#1 1 2 1 2 2   1
#2 1 2 3 4 5   2
#3 1 2 3 4 5   2
#4 3 4 1 2 3   3
#5 3 4 1 2 3   3
```

Hope it helps.